# Transition when switching classes in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and have a DIV containing a picture or video. the div is col-sm-3, but using a jQuery I switch that class with a col-sm-12 on hover. Is there any way to make a smoother transition and add some effects when the resize happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try CSS transitions for good performance:

```
.col-sm-3, .col-sm-12{
    transition: all 200ms; //replace 200ms with time of your choice
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cm3oc7vh/

Comment: This is way easier than I would have imagined! I only have another small problem, though: when the div resizes, I also hide a big div above adding the "hidden" class, so the resized div moves on top. I tried applying the transition property to the hidden class as well, but that doesn't work. Any way to make it disappear slowly as the other div grows? Thanks.

Comment: First set the height of the div above to 0, then wait however long you want the animation, then hide it

Comment: How couldn't I think of this? :D
But still, can't get it to work; the jumbotron div doesn't want to shrink to 0, and stops to a minimum height no matter what. I tried with height and min-height: 0, and hiding overflow, but no luck.. :/

Comment: Try setting both margin and padding to 0 when hiding

Answer (score 0):

You could always use jQuery-UI and the [`switchClass`](http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/) method. This will animate the difference in styles.

```js
$(function($){
    $('#switch').on('click',function(e){
        var $p = $('#target')
        if($p.is('.foo')){
            $p.switchClass('foo','bar',1000);
        }else{
            $p.switchClass('bar','foo',1000);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
.foo { color: red; font-size: 150%; }
.bar { color: blue; font-size: 100%; }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p id="target" class="foo">Hello, world!</p>
<button id="switch">Switch</button>
```

Comment: Good idea, never thought of that. However, it might be a bit overkill to include jQuery UI if all you need is a simple animation.

Comment: @KevinPei: OP can [customize build](http://jqueryui.com/download/) and only include that functionality to keep it more light-weight.

Comment: fair enough. Guess my performance fanaticism is getting to me :P

Comment: This also works very nice, but the CSS transition rule is surely more lightweight. But I'll consider UI if I'll need more effects.
By the way, is there any way to animate a disappearing DIV (adding hidden class), when the resizing DIV below also moves up?

Comment: @Daniele I'm not sure I know what you mean. Like a `fadeTo`?

Comment: Well, I have the a jumbotron div taking all the width of the page, and under that different colums. One of these colums contains a small picture of video; when I hover on it, it grows full width (I replace col-3 with col-12), but I also hide the jumbotron above (by adding a hidden class to it), so the video not only expands, but also moves up in place of the jumbotron. I tried applying the css transition rule to all elements, and the video does expand smoothly but moves up all of a sudden. Hope it's clear what I mean!