# How to add smooth transition to an object using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating an HTML website, in the stage when I'm writing the navbar code. I'm using Bootstrap for the styling, and I have a jQuery function changing the navbar's class regarding the color. I want to have a smooth transition when the colors change. How do I do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 getScroll();
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
 getScroll();
});

function getScroll() {
 var scroll  = $(window).scrollTop();
 if (scroll <= 50) {
  $("#navbar").removeClass("bg-white");
  $("#navbar").addClass("bg-transparent");
 } else {
  $("#navbar").removeClass("bg-transparent");
  $("#navbar").addClass("bg-white");
 }
}
```

```css
.navbar-nav > li {
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-dark">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top" id="navbar">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-fill">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Tutorials</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="">More...</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28141753/4202224) what you want? You could just add a `transition` to the class you are trying to animate in your own css.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it, but is there I way to do so programmatically?

Comment: Well I would prefer the css way, but there would be a way using jQuery UIs animation feature to swtich classes: [switchClass](https://jqueryui.com/switchClass/)

Comment: Afaik there is no easy way to animate classes with normal jQuery, or you would need to use the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function without using the bootstrap class

Comment: Basically, using `$("#navbar").css('transition', 'all 1s');` does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some transition to navbar ID.

```
#navbar {
        transition: all 2s;
    }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 getScroll();
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
 getScroll();
});

function getScroll() {
 var scroll  = $(window).scrollTop();
 if (scroll <= 50) {
  $("#navbar").removeClass("bg-white");
  $("#navbar").addClass("bg-transparent");
 } else {
  $("#navbar").removeClass("bg-transparent");
  $("#navbar").addClass("bg-white");
 }
}
```

```css
.navbar-nav > li {
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
}

#navbar {
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-dark">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top" id="navbar">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-fill">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Tutorials</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="">More...</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
```